# After Upgraded Android app , Not shown upgraded app in Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I upgraded my app in Android Market but till now not reflected in Android Market. How many hours take to reflect updated app in Android Market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In India (which I think where you are), it may take any where around two to three hours.

Comment: Which is pretty good.  Back in the Eclair days it could take over 24/48 hours sometimes for users to see it.  Google has improved it significantly.

Comment: Yeah, but way to go for India. Looking forward to the day, when we(Indians) could also sell our app in the market.